# new R package doesn't recognise dependency

Tags: r, package, roxygen

if I build a simple package that basically get first 10 rows of a dataframe, my R file will be like this:

```
first10row <- function(df) {
  df %>% head(10)
}
```

And in description file I add

```
Imports:
tidyverse
```

In royxgen comment of the function i added

```
@imports tidyverse
```

When build the package it returns an error

```
Error in df %>% head(10) : could not find function "%>%"
```

What's the proper way to import dependency in R code if I need to rely on other packages? I read the namespace file and is still confused. Thanks.

Comment: What is in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) will be worth reading.

Comment: @Gregor NAMESPACE is the default. should i add import(tidyverse) there? Thanks

Comment: @lmo thanks for the link! still digesting it..if I ran devtools::document() 
it returns:
  Dependency package dplyr not available.

Comment: Maybe read the whole thing before asking more questions in comments.

Comment: If you're using roxygen as the tag suggests, you need to add an appropriate roxygen comment so `%>%` gets added to your NAMESPACE file. [Supplementary reading.](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html)

Comment: @alistaire i had some trouble utilize what's in that reading, bear with me for a sec, when run devtools::document() or roxygen2::roxygenise() it shows there is no package called ‘tidyverse’, and i have imports tidyverse in roxygen comment too. that's how i got stuck. i might just read it again when the day breaks..

Comment: @alistaire same link as in lmo's comment above.

Comment: @Gregor Oops, so it is, sorry! I glanced at the URL too quickly and thought it was referring to [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces).

Comment: @santoku [The usual way to do it](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html) is `@importFrom magrittr \`%>%\``